# Nginx response with access.log display 200,but browser con't receive,How to solve?

Tags: nginx

I want to proxy a backend serve with nginx.
I can request data and return true like`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/carnews`
But I want to work  on 80(or any ports) with nginx,
But when I access `http://127.0.0.1/api/carnews` , backend response,and nginx `access.log` display 200 ,But browser is pending(postman the same)

the nginx version is 1.17.3

At first,I use nginx on docker,then on host,but the problem not dissolve.
I ash someone ,they also think is the config right.

I try many times!!!!
And find,when the response length less than 9698. I can receive the data on browser,when the length greater then 9697,the browser on pending.
What a magic length,I try to search on google with it but find none
Ps: origin the backend is on docker,when I start a demo on host,the 9698 limits change to 9729................. 
And the api`http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/carnews` direct access when the length greater than 9697 is also work.So the backend I think is not wrong,maybe the nginx config

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 1;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    upstream nodejs {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        keepalive 64;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 0.0.0.0;
        root /;
        location ~ ^/(api) {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://nodejs;
        }
    }

}
```

access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2019:21:30:46 +0800] "GET /api/carnews HTTP/1.1" 200 9697 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0" browser 200
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Aug/2019:21:31:11 +0800] "GET /api/carnews HTTP/1.1" 200 9698 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.13.0" browser pending and fail
```

Comment: Why do you need nginX in the first place ? Why not simply run nodejs on port 80 and do not bother with all this stuff ?

Comment: for learn docker

Comment: There is nothing in your question which indicates that you are using Docker. Please provide all the information for your case.

Comment: I use on docker,but response fail,so I separation conditions,find seems nginx problem.........
I say for learn docker,is the problem start with docker,now I want to solve this problem,so I can learn continue
PS:event if not learn docker,I also want to solve.

Comment: Try to run nginX outside of Docker, with the above configuration - to confirm that the issue is related to nginX settings and not to Docker settings.

Comment: What's the current state of this?